# Spotfire line chart multiple axis 2 or more columns on left axis with just one scale

Tags: linechart, spotfire

I have a line chart with multiple axis (3 columns on the left and one on the right). I know how to make the right axis use a different scale but is there a way to make the three columns on the left display just one scale instead of one for each line on the left being drawn?

Thank you,

Chris Habrock

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a built-in way to do this. with "Multiple Scales" turned on, Spotfire will create a scale for each column used on the axis.

you could try to combine the three columns into one column. I'm not sure if this will meet your requirements but it's the best workaround I can think of.

if your data is like:

```
ID    val1    val2    val3
1     100     111     121
2     200     222     232
3     300     333     343
...
```

use an unpivot transforation to get:

```
ID    Value    Category    val3*
1     100      val1        121
1     111      val2        121
2     200      val1        232
2     222      val2        232
...
```

***NOTE** that I included [val3] here as a "pass through" column, but I don't recommend doing this. if you try to plot right the above, you'll get duplicate points for [val3].

instead, **Insert...Rows** and insert the [val3] column from your original table. finally, you want something like this:

```
ID    Value    Category    val3*
1     100      val1        
1     111      val2        
2     200      val1        
2     222      val2
1                          121
2                          232
...
```

and then plot your line chart on this. set the vertical axis to [Value],[val3] and then color by [Category]

---

I recommend to do this transformation in a "virtual" table (Add Data Table...From Analysis to make a linked copy of an existing table, then do your manipulations on that table). this way you don't have an issue of altering your other visulizations and your transformed table is always up to date.